# in mysql, how do you get data based on php array with additional filters?

Tags: php, mysql

Say, this is my php array.

```
postids = Array
(
    [0] => 2172
    [1] => 383
    [2] => 2915
    [3] => 677
    [4] => 1289
    [5] => 1654
    [6] => 2252
    [7] => 2366
    [8] => 2998
    [9] => 2442
    [10] => 1246
)
```

Now in mysql table (t1) looks like this.

```
|postid|type|switch|
|1|A|0|
|2|A|1|
|3|A|0|
...
|383|A|0|
...
|1246|A|1|
...
|2172|A|1|
...
|2442|A|0|
```

So, I want to select postid of type 'A' where switch = 1 and order by my php array and includes post ids from my array.

so, is there any query like

```
select postids from t1 where type = 'A' and switch = 1 and postids = {<?php echo postids; ?>}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `order by field()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: There are no current query, also this is not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: so, I am writing an sql query where I am ordering it based on PHP array

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical conditions in the WHERE,

```
           SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='A' AND switch='1'
```

Comment: that did not help.

Comment: i guess you should use AND not and :/  , also u don't have to use the postids in select and where 

select postids from t1 where type = 'A' AND switch = 1